# Renomear arquivos no PowerShell com base na pasta de destino

Tags: powershell

Tenho o caminho `A` e o destino `B`. Este destino se repete para vários clientes conforme a estrutura abaixo mostra:

```
A
-->app.exe
-->server.ini
-->js.png.

B-Cliente 01 
-->app_cliente01.exe
-->server.ini
-->js.png.

B-Cliente 02 
-->app_cliente02.exe
-->server.ini
-->js.png

B-Cliente 03 
-->app_cliente03.exe
-->server.ini
-->js.png.
```

Eu preciso copiar todos os arquivos do diretório `A` para os caminhos do `B`, porém ao fazer essa copia eu precisa renomear os arquivos com parte do nome de destino.

Exemplo: `app.exe` ficaria `app_cliente01.exe` quando copiado para a pasta `B-Cliente 01`.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? Há algum erro quando a cópia é feita?

Comment: Então eu não manjo muito de PowerShell eu queria pelo menos uma ideia para eu começar a pesquisar os comandos e como posso fazer isso

Comment: Ok, se seu objetivo é entender melhor o que está sendo feito, sugiro arregaçar as mangas e praticar. A resposta dada pelo usuário Omni vai te ajudar.
Mas não tem almoço grátis, a maioria dos materiais é em Inglês. Veja os links:<br>
[Windows PowerShell Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd347730.aspx)<br>
[about_Comparison_Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847759.aspx)<br>
[Learn How to Load and Use PowerShell Snap-ins](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/16/learn-how-to-load-and-use-powershell-snap-ins.aspx)<br>
[Create Custom Win

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer o seguinte (a explicação esta na forma de comentários):

```
# Primeiro defina a pasta onde estao os ficheiros a copiar
$caminhoFonteFicheiros = Resolve-Path ".\A"

# Depois defina uma mascara para usar quando for necessario encontrar as pastas de destino
$mascaraDestino = "B-*"

# E defina o caminho onde se encontram as pastas
$caminhoFonteDestino = Get-Location

# Por cada pasta de destino encontrada
foreach($destino in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $caminhoFonteDestino -Filter $mascaraDestino -Directory)) {

    # Crie o nome que vai adicionado aos ficheiros copiados 
    $marcador = ($destino.Name -replace $mascaraDestino).Replace(" ", "").ToLowerInvariant();

    # Agora por cada ficheiro que exista no directorio fonte
    foreach($origem in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $caminhoFonteFicheiros -File)) {

        # Separe a extensao e o nome original
        $extensao = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($origem.FullName);
        $nomeAntigo = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(($origem.FullName))

        # E por fim junte-os de novo com o marcador do directorio actual
        $novoNome = "$nomeAntigo`_$marcador$extensao"

        # Crie o novo caminho do ficheiro juntando o caminho da pasta de destino e o novo nome
        $novoCaminho = Join-Path $destino.FullName $novoNome

        # E por fim copie os ficheiros
        Write-Host "A copiar o ficheiro '$($origem.FullName)' para '$novoCaminho'"
        Copy-Item -Path $origem.FullName -Destination $novoCaminho
    }
}
```